# Grabbing text from URL and showing on pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm taking text from a web server and trying to display the current song on my raspberry pi screen over python. Using an LCD 16x2

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Example using a character LCD connected to a Raspberry Pi or BeagleBone Black.
import math
import time
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup


import Adafruit_CharLCD as LCD


page = urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.0.99:9000/status.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.prettify()
mysong = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'playingSong'}) 
# Print a two line message
lcd.message(mysong)
```

I've taken all the LCD stuff out of above as it works, however mysong isnt being set right. The HTML element i'm trying to get is:

```
 <div class="playingSong"><a href="/songinfo.html?item=683&amp;player=00%3A22%3A19%3A0a%3Af2%3A9f" target="browser">Beetlebum</a>
```

I'm getting the error:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/Adafruit_Python_CharLCD/examples $ sudo python tom.py          Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tom.py", line 46, in <module>
    lcd.message(mysong)
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/Adafruit_CharLCD/Adafruit_CharLCD.py", line 247, in message
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but Tag found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a `BeautifulSoup.ResultSet` (containing `Tag` objects) to `lcd.message()`. Instead you need to first get the element from the result set, and then get the element's text:

```
text = mysong[0].getText()
lcd.message(text)
```

If you know that you only expect one element to match, use `find` instead of `findAll`:

```
mysong = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'playingSong'})
text = mysong.getText()
lcd.message(text)
```